# Find index of TD within siblings

Tags: jquery

I'm refactoring the following code:

```
$(this).parent().find('td').index(this)
```

into this code:

```
$(this).siblings('td').index(this)
```

which baslically searches among the TDs of the current TR by accessing sibling TDs rather than going up to the TR and down again to the TDs.

But where the first code returns `19`, which is correct, the second returns `-1`, which obviously isn't.

I'm puzzled...

Comment: what is `this`? please provide more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
$(this).siblings('td').addBack().index(this)
```

Siblings are actually all other TDs, so I have to include the current TD as well!

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you wanted is:

```
$(this).siblings('td').addBack().index(this)
```

http://api.jquery.com/addBack

Comment: yep! found it as well ;)

Comment: Remember to note that andSelf has been deprecated and should use addBack gng forward for >= 1.8